# Proxy class generation failed by using wsdl command line tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sabre

I tried to generate proxy class by using wsdl command line tool. But I received error message called `"- The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"`
[image]

Is there a way to sort out this error message and generate proxy class successfully?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the wsdl and xsd referenced in it, into files and then use wsdl.exe on the local files.
eg.:

> wsdl QueueMoveLLS2.0.0RQ.wsdl msg-header-2_0.xsd
> STL_For_SabreProtocol_v.1.2.0.xsd STL_Header_v.1.2.0.xsd envelope.xsd
> QueueMoveLLS2.0.0RQRS.xsd wsse.xsd xlink.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
> QueueMoveLLS2.0.0RQ.xsd sws_common.xsd

Another option is to use wsdl's link in Visual Studio to create a service reference.